# Unable to Attach remote debugger to Chrome headless in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm running my E2E test cases using Selenium WebDriver with Chrome headless. this configuration working fine and able run test case.

My code looks like this:

```
 const options = {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            port: PORT,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['disable-infobars' 
                ,'headless',
                'disable-gpu',

            ],
            //binary: '/Applications/Google Chrome Dev.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
            binary: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'

            }
        },
        host: envConfig.seleniumUrl,
        deprecationWarnings: false
    };
    this.browser = webdriverio
        .remote(options)
        .init()
        .url(envConfig.appUrl)
        .timeouts('script', 35000)
        .timeouts('implicit', 35000);
```

Some of my test case failing so i am trying to attach chrome debugger using chrome launch option

> --remote-debugging-port=9222

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

After adding remote debugging port flag My E2E failing and unable to start

```
 const options = {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            port: PORT,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['disable-infobars' 
                ,'headless',
                'disable-gpu',
                '--remote-debugging-port=5552'
            ],
            //binary: '/Applications/Google Chrome Dev.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
            binary: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'

            }
        },
        host: envConfig.seleniumUrl,
        deprecationWarnings: false
    };
```

Error is

```
  chrome not reachable
       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
     Command duration or timeout: 60.09 seconds
     Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
     System info: host: 'xxxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
     Driver info: driver.version: unknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
         at end() - hooks.js:47:25
```

how to fix this initialization issue and how to attach chrome dev tools with headless browser.